# I want to know about infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I have learned infinitive has meaning of possibility. but I think it has meaning of present and past

For example, 1. nice to meet you  2. I remember to go to school

in this example, infinitive has past meaning I am nice because I met you.

but example 2 is like to go to school doesn't happen and it will happen.

I want to know how you guys got it when you guys studied it.

Comment: Alas, native speaker guys didn't study it.  They learned it as children by listening to their parents, absorbing the language in a way not fully understood.  The infinitives you cite don't carry tense, so they don't indicate time.  That's the job of the so-called finite verb.  It was nice to meet you yesterday; it is nice to meet you today; it will be nice to meet you tomorrow.  "To meet" means the same thing independent of the verb tenses in the statements.

Comment: Infinitives take part of their meaning from the main verb they follow. 'I remembered to go to the party' means that you remembered *and* that you went. 'I wanted to go to the party' means that you wanted, but *doesn't* tell us whether you actually went (possibly you did, possibly you didn't).

Comment: I take infinitive mostly as the object of the sentence, not that I really believe it's the object but

Comment: Your meaning for "Nice to meet you" wrong. Try "It was nice (pleasant) to meet you." or "I enjoyed meeting you" or "Meeting you was an event which I enjoyed" or even "I was pleased because I met you". "I was nice" is an entirely different statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is **not the matter of time**. Infinitive is **not a tense** although it's tempting to think so because it includes the base form of a verb.
It's the ***matter of function***. An infinitive can take five functions generally i.e *subject, object, adverb, adjective, and complement*.

I'll just talk about the related functions that you gave an example for.

1. Object.

> He wants to see.

Here 'to see' is the object. 'To see' is generally what he desires.

Now look at this example.

> He wanted to see.

Does it mean that infinitive is referring to the past? To answer this question I'd like to give these examples:

> I want some chocolate now.
>   (I say this sentence now)
>
> I wanted some chocolate an hour ago.
>   (An hour later I say this to describe what I wanted an hour ago)

'Some chocolate' is the direct object of 'want/ed'. Can we talk about the time of 'some chocolate'? Is the chocolate I 'want' and 'wanted' different? I don't think so. It's the *main verb* that specifies when I want chocolate.

As 'some chocolate' in the examples above, 'to see' (in my example) and also 'to go' (in your example) are objects of sentences. They are the noun (or noun substitute) that receives the action of the verb.

2. Complement.

In second example of yours i.e. 
"[it's] nice to meet you", 'to meet you' is an adjective complement i.e. it modifies adjective 'nice'.

Other examples of this sort:

> He was anxious to go out alone.
>
> He's likely to be nominated.

Again as I said in previous part, it's the main verb of the sentence that tells you about the *time* of the action ***not*** the infinitive_here 'is' and 'was'.

And the last point that may help you to get the sentence right is actually *'nice to meet you'* is the short form of *'it's nice to meet you'*. It's not like *'glad to meet you'* which is short for *'I'm glad to meet you'*